# bootstrap bottom sticky footer overlapping with site

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I am using the following markup to create a bottom copyright banner

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">© Some Company</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And here is the CSS

```
 /*         Sticky footer styles
      -------------------------------------------------- */
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      /* Margin bottom by footer height */
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }


    /* Custom page CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

    body > .container {
      padding: 60px 15px 0;
    }
    .container .text-muted {
      margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .footer > .container {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    code {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
```

The issue is that it overlaps with the bottom portion of the site content.

How do I force it to go further down ?

I had no luck with this CSS

```
  .navbar-fixed-bottom {
       padding-top: 10px;  
       height: 5%;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Increase the bottom-padding of your content container.

If this is the the rule for the page content ( I don't know, since you didn't post the complete HTML structure of the page)...

```
body > .container {
      padding: 60px 15px 0;
    }
```

...then change that last "0"  to at least 60px (try different values):

```
body > .container {
      padding: 60px 15px 80px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      /* Margin bottom by footer height */
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .footer {

      position: absolute;
      /*this controls how far bottom the banner goes*/
      top: 110%; <---- THIS WAS THE MISSIN PIECE
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }


    /* Custom page CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

    body > .container {
      padding: 60px 15px 0;
    }
    .container .text-muted {
      margin: 20px 0;
    }

    .footer > .container {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    code {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a margin to the bottom of your page and setting `position: fixed;` in your `.footer` CSS class :

```
body {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Here is a [working example of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/jessejjohnson/7j2h044o/) and an [example from the bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/).

Comment: The bottom margin piece didnt quite help. This CSS component isnt working for me in general. Not sure why